# Java, relative xpath to find web elements

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I am trying to go through a table (id="campaignAllAvailableList") and iterate through a list of titles:
 (`xpath = .//*[@id='campaignAllAvailableList']/li/div/div/h3`) to see if it matches with the one I want.

If it does, then I click onto the corresponding button:

(xpath = `.//*[@id='campaignAllAvailableList']/li/div/div[3]/a`)

```html
<div id="campaignListWrapper" class="campaignOverviewSectionBody campaignListing" style="">
<ul id="campaignAllAvailableList" class="campaignList" style="display: block;">
<li>
<div class="timetableCard clearedGroup">
<div class="timetableCardHeader helpAnchor">
<h3 class="timetableCardTitle">November Campaign metaTitle</h3>
<img class="helpIcon" src="/images/icons/info-icon.png"/>
<div class="popUp helpPopUp">
</div>
<div class="timetableCardBody">
<div class="timetableCardActionBar clearedGroup">
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="timetableCard clearedGroup">
<div class="timetableCardHeader helpAnchor">
<h3 class="timetableCardTitle">qwe</h3>
<img class="helpIcon" src="/images/icons/info-icon.png"/>
<div class="popUp helpPopUp">
</div>
<div class="timetableCardBody">
<div class="timetableCardActionBar clearedGroup">
</div>
</li>
```

This is the java code I have right now:

```
public class PromotionsPage extends MainPageTemplate
{
    @FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='campaignAllAvailableList']/li/div")
    List<WebElement> campaignTable;

public PromotionsPage(WebDriver d) throws PageValidationException
{
    super(d);
}

public void clickSpecificGetStartedButton(String metadataTitle)
{

    for (WebElement el : campaignTable)
    {
        WebElement metadataTitleTextElement = el.findElement(By.xpath(".//div/h3"));
        if (metadataTitle == metadataTitleTextElement.getText())
        {
            WebElement getStartedButton = el.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[3]/a"));
                getStartedButton.click();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is failing at  "for (WebElement el : campaignTable)", I think it is not reading campaignTable as a List properly...

I tried finding the list of title directly

```
@FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='campaignAllAvailableList']/li/div/div/h3")
List<WebElement> campaignTable;
```

and do

```
for (WebElement el : campaignTable)
        {
            System.out.println(el.getText());
}
```

but this is giving an error too,
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

Comment: what is the question exactly? any error ?

Comment: i just included the error in the post -  It is failing at "for (WebElement el : campaignTable)", I think it is not reading campaignTable as a List properly

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML in the question rather than using an image. The image will eventually not be accessible and then this question will be less useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it, but I am still not sure why the original code doesnt work

```
List<WebElement> campaignTable = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='campaignAllAvailableList']/li/div"));  
for (WebElement el : campaignTable)
{
    String metadataTitle = el.findElement(By.xpath(".//div/h3")).getText();

    if (target.compareTo(metadataTitle)==0)
    {
        WebElement getStartedButton = el.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[3]/a"));
        getStartedButton.click();
        break;
    }
}``
```

Comment: see that `FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='campaignAllAvailableList']/li/div")`is not working and you added `break`

Answer (score 0):

insert a `break;` after clicking the element to escape from the loop. See below:

```
public void clickSpecificGetStartedButton(String metadataTitle)
{
for (WebElement el : campaignTable)
{
    WebElement metadataTitleTextElement = el.findElement(By.xpath(".//div/h3"));
    if (metadataTitle == metadataTitleTextElement.getText())
    {
        WebElement getStartedButton = el.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[3]/a"));
            getStartedButton.click();
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: it fails at the line of 'for (WebElement el : campaignTable)', so the break doesnt really help